# How to apply additional constraints on fsolve?

Tags: matlab, function

This is a very simplified form of my problem.  I have two unknowns: *x(1)* and *x(2)*, where (i) *x(1)* is an integer in *[1,5]*, and (ii) *x(2)* lies between 0 and 1. I wish to solve an equation given in the second set of codes below, such that it picks the highest possible *x(1)* that satisfies the equation and satisfies condition (ii).  This solution must be unique.

I thought I should apply some additional constraints in the function.  So far, I have the following ``mother'' code:

```
v = 1;
fun = @root;
x0 = [1,5];
options = optimset('MaxFunEvals',100000,'MaxIter', 10000 );
x = fsolve(fun,x0, options)
```

The function that I am referring is the following:

```
function D = root(x)
 D(1) = x(1)./5 + x(2) - .8;
end
```

Comment: check out [`lsqnonlin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/nonlinear-systems-with-constraints.html#btsimp_)

Comment: I already did, but it doesnt seem to help much...

Comment: it lets you add upper and lower bounds, you can set `x0(1)` with the highest possible value, and you can add a cost term for the value of `x0(1)` (like: `cost = @(x) (5-x(1))^2`)

Comment: @user2999345 The problem is not related only to bounds. I need to specify that `x(1)` is an integer too